# stored procedure to eliminate duplicate data

Tags: sql

How to check the names if already present in a2 which are in a1 and if name is not there in a2 only then insert into a2 through pl/sql

```
SQL> select * from a1;

NAME
--------------------
ashok
bahrath
manoj
anoop


SQL> select * from a2;

NAME
--------------------
manoj
bahrath
ashok
sharath
```

Comment: This seems more like a SQL question than a Vaadin one. And even so it's too broad, you should try to give more details and make your problem clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Just a basic `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` statement will work here:

```
INSERT INTO A2
SELECT A1.NAME 
FROM A1 
WHERE A1.NAME NOT IN (SELECT A2.NAME FROM A2);
```

To Tony Spark's point, in the unlikely event that this query is giving you problems, get a new database. (Just Kidding...) The Left Outer Join version should work:

```
INSERT INTO A2
SELECT A1.NAME 
FROM A1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN A2 ON A1.Name = A2.Name
WHERE A2.Name IS NULL;
```

Comment: In statements are limited by the database system used, some only support 1000 -1500 items ,I believe a left outer join would have been a better choice

Comment: Thanks, @TonyStark42. Added.

Comment: @TonyStark42: The "limit" that you _might_ be thinking about is a limit for the number of **constant** values for the  `IN` operator, e.g. `x in (1,2,3)`. Several DBMS do indeed have a limit for that. But no modern DBMS has a limit on the number of rows it can process with a sub-select.